# Adding rows dynamically vs using list adapters

Tags: android, dynamic, listadapter, tablerow

What are the advantages and disadvantages of adding table rows dynamically to a TableLayout compared to using a custom list adapter?

Comment: huge advantage of list adapters: performance

Answer (score 0):

As @binnyb said ListView gives you a huge performance advantage.  If you implement the Adapter properly then you will only have a handful of views inflated at any given time, even if your ListView 'contains' thousands of entries.